# Delete columns Vertically by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to delete columns vertically in salesforce by using javascript. I am using `apex:repeat` for each td in the table.
My requirement is that when I will click on delete icon it will delete that column and next column  will be moved ahead.

My code is like this
:

```
    <apex:outputPanel id="OfferTbld">
    <table class="table choose-offers-table" >
       <thead>

          <th></th>
          <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
           <th>
             <apex:image id="DeleteImage" value="/img/func_icons/remove12_on.gif" onclick="deleteRow({!O.Index})">
                 <apex:param id="imgidx" value="{!O.Index}" assignTo="{!getIndex}"/>
             </apex:image>
           </th>
        </apex:repeat>
       </thead>                              
       <tbody>
         <tr>
               <td>Terms</td>
               <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
               <td id="TermOffer{!O.Index}" ><apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Terms_In_Months__c}" rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Terms_In_Months__c}" styleClass="OfferTermClass" onkeyup="onChangeTerm(this.value);" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}"/></td>
               </apex:repeat>

         </tr>                            
          <tr>
               <td>Advance Amount</td>
               <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
               <td id="AdvanceOffer{!O.Index}"><apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Funding_Amount__c}" rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Funding_Amount__c}" onkeyup="onchangeFunding(this.value);" styleClass="OfferFundedClass" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}"/></td>
               </apex:repeat>

         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>Payback</td>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
               <td id="PaybackOffer{!O.Index}" ><apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Payback_Amount__c}" rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Payback_Amount__c}" styleClass="OfferPaybackClass" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}" html-disabled="true"/></td>
               </apex:repeat>
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <td>Factor</td>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
               <td id="Factor{!O.Index}" > <apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Factor_Rate__c}" rendered="{!O.IsEditable}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Factor_Rate__c}" onkeyup="onChangeFactor(this.value)" styleClass="OfferFactorClass" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}"/></td>
               </apex:repeat>
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <td>Daily Payback Amount</td>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
               <td id="DailyPB{!O.Index}"><apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Daily_PB_Amount__c}" rendered="{!O.IsEditable}" />
               <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Daily_PB_Amount__c}" styleClass="OfferDailyClass" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}" html-disabled="true"/></td>
               </apex:repeat>
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <td>Percentage Of Gross</td>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
               <td id="Percentage{!O.Index}"><apex:outputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Percentage_Of_Gross__c}" rendered="{!O.IsEditable}" />
               <apex:inputField value="{!O.Offer.fintechLLC__Percentage_Of_Gross__c}" styleClass="OfferPerGrossClass" rendered="{!!O.IsEditable}" html-disabled="true"/></td>
               </apex:repeat>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>Actions</td>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfferWrapper}" var="O">
               <td id="Action{!O.Index}"><apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!EditOffer}" reRender="OfferTbld"> 
                     <apex:param name="idx" value="{!O.Index}" assignTo="{!getIndex}"/>
                   </apex:commandLink>&nbsp;
                   <apex:commandLink value="Save" action="{!SaveOffer}" reRender="OfferTbld">
                     <apex:param name="idx" value="{!O.Index}" assignTo="{!getIndex}" />
                   </apex:commandLink>&nbsp;
                   <apex:commandLink value="Cancel" action="{!CancelOffer}" reRender="OfferTbld">
                    <apex:param name="idx" value="{!O.Index}" assignTo="{!getIndex}"/>
                   </apex:commandLink>
               </td>
               </apex:repeat>
         </tr>                                  
       </tbody>
    </table>
    </apex:outputPanel>

 function deleteRow(val)
  {
     console.log('In DeleteRow Function------>'+val);
     var Term=document.getElementById("TermOffer"+val);


     console.log('Term---->'+Term+'Advance------'+Advance+'Payback------->'+Payback+'Factor-------->'+Factor+'DailyPB--------->'+DailyPB+'Percentage------->'+Percentage);

     if(val!=null){

        Term.deleteCell(val);

     }

  }
```

**Before Delete**

[image]

**After Delete**
[image]

Comment: What JavaScript code have you tried to make this happen?

Comment: @Aziz: Please suggest any other method

Comment: I'm not suggesting, I'm asking what have you tried...

Comment: @Aziz: Kindly check the new code. I have added new code